# potential security vulnerability mail from github for my django project

Tags: python, django

Why I am getting this kind mail from github? I am a Python/Django developer. Most of my project contains django dependencies in a requirements.txt file. And my requirements.txt file contains as follows -

```
Django==1.11.9
pytz==2018.5
```

Subject: One of your dependencies may have a security vulnerability

Body:

shahjalalh,
We found a potential security vulnerability in a repository for which you have been granted security alert access.

[image]

Comment: It's because your dependency has a known vulnerability…

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you're confused. You're getting that warning because you are using a version of Django that has security vulnerabilities. You should upgrade to a version where they are fixed.